# jQuery mouse movement becomes invalid on second mousedown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a very simple div where I want to let the user click and drag then collect the 2 coord sets.  Seems like it should be very easy.  I bind the mousedown and collect the offsets the I was going to use the mousemove to track where the mouseup happened.  I tried to get coordinates of the mouse on the mouseup but that didn't seem to work, so I am trying to use the move.

However the click and drag works once but on the second try I get the invalid pointer.  To test use this fiddle and click/drag  then try again.

[To test use this fiddle and click/drag  then try again.](http://jsfiddle.net/a4BqB/56/)

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work at all.

Comment: It is better to not bind thoose events to the canvas area but the document or the body. Your script can get confused if the user mousedown inside the canvas and mouse up outside. If you bind the event to document you just have to check wheter the event originated from the canvas.

Comment: The fiddle actually doesn't do anything other than show on the second click and drag the mouse pointer changes to the invalid pointer

Comment: I was going to add a containment to keep the drag inside the div.

Comment: OK looks like I figured it out.  I had to add an e.preventDefault() to both the mousedown and mouseup events.  That did it just fine.  Thanks for the thoughts.